# NoSuchWindowException : Unable to get browser after clicking an element

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The IEDriver works fine for me at the beginning when I enter a website but then after clicking an element the browser enters a new page and then my application throws this exception `NoSuchWindowException : Unable to get browser`.

***I'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, IE11 and that only happens for sites starting with http://. Sites starting with https:// are fine.***

For example, for the site http://www.gov.ns.ca/snsmr/access/business/registry-joint-stock-companies.asp, after the "Search our database"is clicked by my code it enters the new page, then the browser loses its control to that page.

The code to click the element is like

```
_browser.FindElementByClassName(m.Groups["MethodValue"].Value.Replace("<SP>", " ")).Click();

string url2 = string.Format("[href*=\"{0}\"]", m.Groups["MethodValue"].Value.Replace("<SP>", " "));                                    
_browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector(url2)).Click();
```

I think the code itself is correct because it works for other sites.

I have enabled the protected mode and added the key `HKEYLOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATUREBFCACHE` in registry editor but it still doesn't work.

**I wonder if it's some setting problem with the server.**

Comment: I enabled the protected mode and added the key HKEYLOCALMACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATUREBFCACHE in registry editor but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Post the code snippet that is responsible for clicking the link, both test and code behind.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue and the registry entry did not work for me either.